# Book on people controlling insect exoskeletons

Tags: story-identification

I read this a while back; it's dystopian. There is an alien race that has taken over Earth and in battle use insect suits; the remainder of the humans either think nothing happened (windows on the bus are screens projecting countryside or city) or rebelling against the aliens in their own insect suits. It is a young adult sci-fi made 2 or 3 years ago. I think it has a one-word title but I could be wrong. The main character is a boy with a very common name like Ben, Sam or maybe Jack. there is also another boy and a girl

Comment: Can you remember any other details? When did you read it; roughly when was it written, what did the cover look like; any proper names; etc?

Answer (score 4):

I am fairly certain you are thinking of [The Resisters](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8712426-the-resisters), by Eric S. Nylund, published in 2011.

[image: Cover of book. Features three young people at the bottom and a large flying insect above them.]

The protagonist's name is Ethan. Aliens have taken over the world through mind control and are mining the Earth for its resources. The screens on the windows of the buses hide the barren landscape that is being created. The mind control doesn't affect children, so the resistance must recruit them to fight while the adults live underground. Just like you said, there is another boy and girl, Felix and Madison.

I think it was for younger children, though, not young adults.